# rpmbuild not taking $LD_LIBRARY_CONFIG

Tags: rpm

I'm trying to build Agent++ into an RPM that installs into an alternative location. It's complaining that it can't find libsnmp++. I have libsnmp++ installed, also in an alternative location. $LD_LIBRARY_PATH lists the correct path for libsnmp++. In fact, if I go into the BUILD directory and run the exact configure command in config.log, it works. Why isn't rpmbuild picking up the environment variable for $LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

EDIT:
So it's probably not LD_LIBRARY_CONFIG. If I run the command below as rpmbuild

```
/usr/bin/pkg-config --exists --print-errors 'snmp++-3 >= 3.3.0'
```

that works. But when I put that same line into the %prep section of my build file and run rpmbuild -bp, I get an error saying that the Package snmp++-3 couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is either a bug in rpmbuild or a "feature" in RHEL. This has been an issue since RHEL5 and it doesn't look like they intend on fixing it. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=569773